# Getting MappingException when reading TINYINT value from H2 database as boolean/Boolean

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I am using R2DBC H2 for integration testing my reactive application (which is based on Spring Webflux , Java).

Versions

- Driver: io.r2dbc:r2dbc-h2:0.8.4.RELEASE (Spring boot 2.3.2.RELEASE)
- Java: 11
- OS: Mac

I have a table defined like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `prep_task` (
  `id` SERIAL,
  `external_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `is_active` TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And corresponding entity:

```java
@Table("prep_task")
public class PrepTaskEntity implements Persistable<Long> {
  @Id
  @Column("id")
  private Long id;

  @Column("external_id")
  private String externalId;

  @Column("name")
  private String name;

  @Column("description")
  private String description;

  @Column("is_active")
  private boolean isActive;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getExternalId() {
    return externalId;
  }

  public void setExternalId(String externalId) {
    this.externalId = externalId;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive;
  }

  public void setActive(boolean active) {
    isActive = active;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    return id == null;
  }


}
```

**No issue when saving `PrepTaskEntity` but when trying to read, getting the following error**:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Could not read property @org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column(value="is_active")private java.lang.Boolean com.example.demosvc.persistence.entities.PrepTaskEntity.isActive from result set!
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:172) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.example.demosvc.controllers.PrepTaskController#getPrepTasksForGivenBU(String) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ com.example.demosvc.filters.TenancyContextFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/sites/BU-002/prepTasks" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:172) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.read(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:133) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.read(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:116) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.EntityRowMapper.apply(EntityRowMapper.java:46) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.EntityRowMapper.apply(EntityRowMapper.java:29) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
        at io.r2dbc.h2.H2Result.lambda$map$0(H2Result.java:67) ~[r2dbc-h2-0.8.4.RELEASE.jar:0.8.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.3.8.RELEASE.jar:3.3.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.8.RELEASE.jar:3.3.8.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Byte] to type [java.lang.Boolean]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:263) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readValue(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:187) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:169) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.read(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:133) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.read(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:116) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.EntityRowMapper.apply(EntityRowMapper.java:46) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.EntityRowMapper.apply(EntityRowMapper.java:29) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.h2.H2Result.lambda$map$0(H2Result.java:67) ~[r2dbc-h2-0.8.4.RELEASE.jar:0.8.4.RELEASE]
```

Just FYI I am using MySQL as connection mode for H2.

```java
@Configuration
@Profile(Application.Profiles.INTEGRATION_TEST)
public class H2ConnectionConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

  private final R2dbcConfigProperties r2dbcConfigProperties;

  @Autowired
  public H2ConnectionConfig(R2dbcConfigProperties r2dbcConfigProperties) {
    this.r2dbcConfigProperties = r2dbcConfigProperties;
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    RoutingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new RoutingConnectionFactory();
    Map<String, ConnectionFactory> factories = new HashMap<>();
    H2ConnectionConfiguration.Builder configurationBuilder = H2ConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .property(H2ConnectionOption.MODE, "MySQL")
        .property(H2ConnectionOption.DB_CLOSE_DELAY, "-1")
        .property(H2ConnectionOption.DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT, "false");
    for (String tenant : r2dbcConfigProperties.getTenants()) {
      String databaseName = r2dbcConfigProperties.getDbPrefix() + tenant;
      factories.put(tenant, new H2ConnectionFactory(configurationBuilder.inMemory(databaseName).build()));
    }
    connectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactories(factories);
    connectionFactory.setDefaultTargetConnectionFactory(factories.get("default"));
    return connectionFactory;
  }

}
```

Comment: I think the issue maybe that you are using boolean value (primitive).  Try using Boolean (wrapper), and I think it may fix your issue.

Comment: @gagarwa Tried with Boolean too. Same case. See the updated stacktrace

Comment: Can you update your table to map isActive to BIT/BOOL/BOOLEAN?  That is what is recommended.  The issue is that there is no converter from Byte (mapped to tinyint) to Boolean.  I have also mapped Integer to Boolean (in DB2), but not sure if this is a type issue (int vs byte) or a db issue that it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @gagarwa if that is the case with H2, then i should define separate sql script for H2 and separate for the main application. Coz the main one uses Mysql db and it doesnt have BOOLEAN type. That's why used TINYINT

Comment: @gagarwa you are saying this is what is recommended? Is this mentioned anywhere? Is this an open issue with R2DBC-H2? coz in the non-reactive world, it wasnt a problem

Comment: I think saka1029 answered your question below.  If you are using different dbs, that should be fine... however mysql DOES support boolean type: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html.

Comment: @gagarwa you are correct, but the Mysql version being used isnt v8 unfortunately. So I have to go ahead with this workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document [Data Types](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html) says

> **TINYINT**
> Possible values are: -128 to 127.
> See also integer literal grammar. **Mapped to java.lang.Byte**.

So you should change you DTO class like this:

```
@Table("prep_task")
public class PrepTaskEntity implements Persistable<Long> {

    // .....

    @Column("is_active")
    private Byte isActive;

    // .....

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive != null && isActive != 0;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        isActive = (byte) (active ? 1 : 0);
    }

    // .....

}
```

Comment: I would say you should use the proper Boolean type, but this is a valid workaround...which I have used myself for legacy applications.